# Retrieving all "Yahoo Answers" Questions that contain a certain word . Issue with rate limiting

Tags: python, api, yahoo-api

So, I'm trying to compile a database of all the questions in Yahoo Answers that contain a certain word.  I am currently doing this with the following script I wrote, using Pynswers wrapper class for calling Yahoo API

```
from Answers import Answers

app = Answers()
wbk = xlwt.Workbook()


sheet = wbk.add_sheet('sheet 1')

app.appid = '...'
questions = app.questionSearch({'query':'tornado',})

#Write all column headings
sheet.write(0,0, 'Question')
sheet.write(0,1,'Answer')
sheet.write(0,2, 'Date')
sheet.write(0,3,'Number of Answers')


for i, value in enumerate(questions):
        content = value['Content'].strip()
        chosenAnswer = value['ChosenAnswer'].strip()
        date = value['Date'].strip()
        numAnswers = value['NumAnswers'].strip()

        #Write values into respect columns, (row, column)
        sheet.write(i+1,0,content)
        sheet.write(i+1,1,chosenAnswer)
        sheet.write(i+1,2,date)
        sheet.write(i+1,3,numAnswers)


wbk.save('C://test.xls')
```

The issue is that I only get about 10 responses from this query, and I can't figure out a way to expand the range of questions that I get.  Any ideas?

Comment: I actually dont know if it is, I think it depends on the country, site etc. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping

Comment: The OP is using the Yahoo APIs, so this isn't a matter of web scraping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pynswers](http://code.google.com/p/pynswers/) appears to be a very loose wrapper around the [Yahoo API itself](http://developer.yahoo.com/answers/V1/questionSearch.html). The API documentation shows to use a "start" and "results" field in the request:

So, perhaps you can do the following:

```
first_50 = app.questionSearch({'query':'tornado', 'start' : 0, 'results' : 50})
next_50 = app.questionSearch({'query':'tornado', 'start' : 50, 'results' : 50})
```

**Edit**

Also, in regard to "rate limiting", [Yahoo states in regard to their API](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/faq/) (this section taken on March 7, 2013):

> How many times can I call YQL in a minute/hour/day?
>
> Rate limits in YQL
> are based on your authentication. If you use IP-based authentication,
> then you are limited to 2,000 calls/hour/IP to the public YQL Web
> service URL (/v1/public/*) or 20,000 calls/hour/IP to the private YQL
> Web service URL (/v1/yql/*) that requires OAuth authorization. See the
> YQL Web Service URLs for the public and private URLs. Applications
> (identified by an Access Key) are limited to 100,000 calls/day/key*.
> However, in order to make sure the service is available for everyone
> we ask that you don't call YQL more than 0.2 times/second or 1,000
> times/hour for IP authenticated users and 2.7 times/second or 10,000
> times/hour.
>
> *Please don't create multiple keys to 'avoid' rate limits. If you would like us to increase your limit please contact us with details of
> your project and we'll do our best to accommodate you.

Obviously, you'll need to be careful with your code to ensure that you're getting the information you need without exceeding the rate limit. So, getting "all" the answers might not be practical.

Comment: Thanks for this, and I have done this very thing.  My question, and I should have been more specific on this, is how to get beyond the 50 queries with multiple requests.

Comment: Got it, let me try this and I'll let you know.  I didn't realize there was a 'start' field.

Comment: Hmm- maybe you can think of a way around this.  According to Yahoo API- the maximum 'start' can go to is 1000.  So I can only scrape a total of 1050.   Any ideas?

Comment: No, I don't know if there is a way around it, and considering that they added the restriction (which is actually more work then allowing you to use any number you want), I imagine there is a reason for this restriction. I've seen similar restrictions elsewhere. Perhaps the reason for this restriction might be a good topic for another StackOverflow question.

Comment: @Parseltongue asked the restriction question, but it was closed by a moderator. I commented: Most "search" APIs like this (especially from Yahoo and Google) will have a limited range of results you can get for a given query. The reasons: 1) presumably the most useful results will appear in the first few pages of results and 2) prevent other sites or apps from doing a full extraction of the data.

Comment: Thanks for cross-posting the reply, I never saw that.